# How to Cross Join Same Column (on itself)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to Cross Join or create a Cartesian Product of one column (on itself) that shows all the possible combinations there are.

This is the idea I had, but I'm hit with several errors when I attempt to run it:

```
SELECT Product_ID as 'Item1' and Product_ID as 'Item2'
FROM `bpd.js.fp`
CROSS JOIN `bpd.js.fp`
on Product_ID
```

The results would look something like this (2 columns),

Product1     Product1

Product1     Product2

Product1     Product3

Product2     Product1

Product2     Product2

....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use alias like I do and `CROSS JOIN` without the `ON` clause for a Cartesian product.

```
SELECT T1.Product_ID AS Item1, T2.Product_ID AS Item2
FROM `bpd.js.fp` AS T1
CROSS JOIN `bpd.js.fp` AS T2
```